# Symfony - Can't thow my createNotFoundException in Action

Tags: php, symfony, exception, throw

I've created entity product and I can't throw exceptions when I want use function `getProduct` or `deleteProduct` and the product doesn't exists in database.

My code:

```
/**
 * @Route("/product/{product}", name="get_product", methods={"GET"})
 */
public function getProduct(Product $product)
{
    if(!$product){
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Product not found');
    }

    return JsonResponse::create(['id' => $product->getId(), "name" => $product->getName(), "price" => $product->getPrice(), "description" => $product->getDescription()]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/product/{product}", name="delete_product", methods={"DELETE"})
 */
public function deleteProduct(Product $product)
{
    if(!$product){
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Product not found');
    }

    $this->em->remove($product);
    $this->em->flush();

    return JsonResponse::create('deleted');
}
```

Comment: So what exactly happens? "My car is not driving anymore" isn't enough. Is the response rendered? Doesn't it enter the if case? I guess that $product is not empty or null ...

Comment: It didn't enter the if case, but it's already solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type hinting already expect a `Product` object.

```
public function deleteProduct(Product $product)
{
    // $product is never null
    dump($product->getName());
```

The code above is the same than  below

```
public function deleteProduct($productId)
{
    $product = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Product::class)
        ->find($productId);
    // $product could be null
    if(!$product){
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Product not found');
    }
    // $product is never null
    dump($product->getName());
```

Because Symfony paramTransformer throw a NotFoundException when the object is not matched. see the doc for more in depth info